# Grafana UI does not load when deployed through helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, prometheus-operator

I am trying to deploy the kube-prometheus-stack.

I have added it as a dependency in the Chart.yaml as below.

```yaml
...
dependencies:
  - name: kube-prometheus-stack
    version: 13.4.1
    repository: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
...
```

I have also configured an ingress rule to route the /grafana/?(.*) path to the service solutions-helm-grafana at port 80.

```yaml
- path: /grafana/?(.*)
  pathType: Prefix
  backend:
    service:
      name: helm-grafana
      port:
        number: 80
```

However, when I try open /grafana/ in the browser, it returns a 404 after redirecting to /login. What templates do I need to add to successfully deploy ? Are there any examples that I can refer to ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @Moses can you try removing the ?(.*) from the path?

404 comes up when the ingress is not registered with the ingress controller.

Probably because the release has not been deployed successfully.

Try the following steps to debug the issue:-

- Check if the pod have been deployed using `kubectl get pods`.
- Try debugging the ingress object. `kubectl describe ing <ing_object_name>`.
- Check if the Endpoints have been created using `kubectl get ep`.
- Next,get the service endpoint using `kubectl get service`.
- Use a busybox pod to curl and check whether the Grafana is being served via the service above.

Update:-
Add the following configuration to serve Grafana on a subpath

```
env:
  GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: <domain>
  GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: https://<domain>/grafana/
  GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: true
```

and use this path in ingress:

```
path: /grafana/
```

Sources:
[Run Grafana behind reverse-proxy](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/#1)
[Grafana confiugration root_url](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/configuration/#root_url)

Comment: [rohatgisanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551228/rohatgisanat) Thanks. I did try the steps mentioned by you. All the pods, ingresses, endpoints and services are deploying correctly. What I do feel is that I need to somehow figure out how to set a root path or subpath so that webpages are served correctly from grafana,

Comment: Hi @Moses have you tried curl within busybox using service/grafana?Also try removing the regex expr at the end. If thats working then your ingress is the issue. You can further look into ingress controller whether it is reading your ingress objects. (look into the annotations as well)

Comment: @Moses Added the solution.

Comment: [rohatgisanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551228/rohatgisanat) I tried it but it din't work. Maybe there's something more I need to change. Thanks for the solution though. It helped me understand how to set the environment variables.

Comment: ```
grafana:
  env:
    GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: <grafana_service_name>
    GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: http://<grafana_service_name>:3000/grafana/
    GF_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: true
```
 It worked. Thanks [rohatgisanat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551228/rohatgisanat). I was under the impression that the port number was **80** as that was displayed in `kubectl get services`. On listing the endpoints, port **3000** was displayed. So in the ingress.yaml, we route to service port 80. But in the environment variable GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL, we use port 3000.

Comment: @Moses Nice!  I usually use the busybox pod to curl pod ip,ep,svc in that oder to identify where the issue could be.